# Complex text formatting ASP.NET/C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

Accused to be not detailed enough, now I'll try to be detailed and descriptive as possible.

So, I have web application with textbox. Next to it I made label for preview, so when I click Submit, it sends text to remote application, when I press preview, it sends text to label for preview.

Remote application have specific text formatting, so When I type `A` text becomes red, `B`, text becomes green, and so on. When I wan't to change color, I type this sign for new color, I can't close color (like in HTML).
For new line, I also have a sign, it's @r
I also have sign for double width.

Main problem is to do following things:

1. Count characters and spaces, and break line on last space before 30th sign (replace space with @r (new row sign), so space wouldn't be taken to next row).
   None of the @x(x is some letter) should be counted, as they just do text formatting.
2. While counting characters, when it comes to %Y (sign for double letter's width), it should count double those letters and spaces until it comes to @Z or @W, where normal letters with starts again, and from that point, count again one by one letter.

If anything is not clear enough, please ask.

Comment: "Being descriptive", please, better publish your code as describe it. One line of code is worth one paragraph or even more!

Comment: everything is clear, but what is your problem? Your algorithm seems properly defined, now you just translate it into c# and you're fine

Comment: @Zruty, I'm not that good at C#, so I need little help how to write this in C#.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can access individual characters in a string that you get from the TextBox, and iterate over them:

```
StringBuilder newString = new StringBuilder();

for (int index = 0; index < textBox.Text.Length; index++)
{
   char myChar = textBox.Text[index];

   ... apply your logic as need one char at a time...
   ... you might need extra variables outside of the loop to 
   ... keep track of your last space before 30th character, etc. 

   newString.Append(...);
}

string result = newString.ToString();
```